# Python threading Condition

Tags: python, condiciones, hilos

Buenas tardes a tod@s!

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de clase usando Condition(), Notifiy(), Acquire() y Release(), en el que me piden lo siguiente:

- Creo 20 hilos desde "main"
- Cada hilo debe acceder a una funcion "beberDelVaso"
- Si pueden beber, beben durante un tiempo (entre 1 y 10 segundos) y si no, esperan 0.5 segundos hasta
  poder intentarlo de nuevo
- Cuando terminan de beber, lo notifican y entra el siguiente

Llevo horas buscando por la web y viendo videos y no acabo de entender el funcionamiento. He intentado hacerlo con una funcion "producer" y otra "consumer", pero cuando me enfrento a...

```
with cond:
    cond.wait() o cond.notify()
```

...no entiendo nada. Y ni siquiera sé si esa es la manera, porque el enunciado no me da a entender que deba crear dos funciones (ni un hilo "productor"), sino solo la de beber del vaso.

Si alguien me pudiera explicar todo esto sería maravilloso.

Lo poco que tengo hasta ahora es esto, porque voy probando y probando...

```
import threading
import time
from random import randint

cond = threading.Condition()

def beber():
    global cond
    s = randint(1, 10)
    print(f'El hilo {threading.currentThread().getName()} empina el codo duante {s} segundos')
    time.sleep(s)
    cond.notify()
    print('Algo perjudicado, el hilo {} se retira'.format(threading.current_thread().name))
    cond.release()


def controlDeAccesoAlBar():
    global cond
    while not (cond.acquire()):
        cond.wait(0.5)
    else:
        beber()

def ejercicio4():
    hilos = []

    for i in range(20):
        t = threading.Thread(target=controlDeAccesoAlBar(), name=('t' + str(i + 1)))
        hilos.append(t)
        t.start()

    for i in range(len(hilos)):
        hilos[i].join()

    print('¡El bar cierra!')
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Te pusieron alguna restricción u obligación respecto a lo que puedes ocupar? ¿Tiene que ser obligatoriamente con las funciones que señalas?

Comment: Si, este ha de ser con Conditions(). En el ejercicio anterior ya hicimos algo parecido con Lock() y en otro con Semaphore() y ambos fueron mucho más fáciles de entender para mí.

Comment: Cuantos vasos hay? si hay un solo vaso, cada consumidor tendra suerte si lo puede agarrar.. mientras todo el resto mira... Podes mostrarnos uno de tus intentos reales a ver donde puiste fallar?

Comment: Si, hay un solo vaso. Cuando un hilo bebe, lo hace durante randint(1,10), y si no puede beber porque la zona critica esta ocupada, espera 0.5seg antes de volver a intentarlo. No os puedo mostrar ningun intento, porque no he conseguido hacer nada util :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toda la acción está en la función `beberDelVaso`.

La función `Condition.acquire(blocking=True, timeout=-1)` tiene dos formas de operar: con bloqueo o sin bloqueo:

- Cuando se llama con `acquire(True)`, la función se bloquea y no retorna hasta adquirir el `lock`.
- Cuando se llama con `acquire(False)`, la función retorna de inmediato, con resultado `True` si pudo adquirir el `lock` o `False`, en caso contrario.

Para esperar hasta obtener el vaso, usamos `acquire(False)`. Si no se pudo obtener el `lock`, la función retorna `False` y ahí podemos esperar 0.5 segundos antes del siguiente intento.

```
def beberDelVaso(cond):
    while not cond.acquire(False):
        time.sleep(0.5)

    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
    cond.release()

    nombre = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f"Thread {nombre} terminada")
```

Para este ejercicio no se necesitan las otras funciones `notify` o `wait`, ya que cada hilo es independiente y no produce o consume nada de los otros hilos.

El resto del código queda igual:

```
def ejercicio4():
    hilos = []
    cond = threading.Condition()

    for i in range(20):
        nombre = f"t{i+1}"
        print(f"Lanzando thread {nombre}")
        t = threading.Thread(target=beberDelVaso, name=nombre, args=(cond, ))
        hilos.append(t)
        t.start()

    for i in range(len(hilos)):
        hilos[i].join()

    print('¡El programa ha finalizado!')

ejercicio4()
```

**Demo**

```
Lanzando thread t1
Lanzando thread t2
Lanzando thread t3
Lanzando thread t4
Lanzando thread t5
Lanzando thread t6
Lanzando thread t7
Lanzando thread t8
Lanzando thread t9
Lanzando thread t10
Lanzando thread t11
Lanzando thread t12
Lanzando thread t13
Lanzando thread t14
Lanzando thread t15
Lanzando thread t16
Lanzando thread t17
Lanzando thread t18
Lanzando thread t19
Lanzando thread t20
Thread t1 terminada
Thread t8 terminada
Thread t3 terminada
Thread t11 terminada
Thread t16 terminada
Thread t2 terminada
Thread t19 terminada
Thread t5 terminada
Thread t9 terminada
Thread t18 terminada
Thread t6 terminada
Thread t17 terminada
Thread t10 terminada
Thread t13 terminada
Thread t14 terminada
Thread t4 terminada
Thread t15 terminada
Thread t7 terminada
Thread t20 terminada
Thread t12 terminada
¡El programa ha finalizado!
```

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de haber marcado la respuesta de CandidMoe como buena, tambien voy a publicar la que finalmente me dijo mi profesor. Cualquiera de la dos funciona bien, pero en el ejercicio que estaba haciendo se esperaba que usara wait() y por tanto notify().

Espero que le sirva a alguien en un futuro.

```
def beber():
    global cond
    rnd = randint(1, 10)
    print(f'El hilo {threading.currentThread().name} bebe duante {rnd} segundos')
    time.sleep(rnd)
    print('El hilo {} termina de beber'.format(threading.current_thread().name))
    cond.notify(1)
    cond.release()

def salaDeEspera():
    global cond
    # Los hilos acceden aqui todos a la vez, y pasado este sleep continúan desordenados
    # porque el SO ya se encarga de ir asignando la tarea a cada hilo
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while not cond.acquire():
        cond.wait(0.5)
    else:
        beber()


def ejercicio4():
    hilos = []
    for i in range(20):
        t = threading.Thread(target=salaDeEspera, name=('t' + str(i + 1)))
        hilos.append(t)
        print("Hilo {} preparado!".format(t.name))

    for i in range(len(hilos)):
        hilos[i].start()

    for i in range(len(hilos)):
        hilos[i].join()

    print('¡El bar cierra!')
```

Supongo, aunque esto es solo una suposición, que la respuesta de CandidMoe no pone al hilo en estado de "espera", mientras que el wait() sí.

Answer (score 0):

Vengo también a dejar mi propia solución.
Me pareció un divertido problema y me sirvió para aprender más sobre threading.
Espero que a alguien le pueda servir por si no entiende o no le sirven las respuestas anteriores.
Dejo también otro buen ejemplo que puede ser utilizado para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento de esta librería [Ejemplo SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12686939/10712525)

Reducí el rango de tiempo de 1-10 segundos a 1-3 segundos y la cantidad de hilos de 20 a 5.

```py
import threading
import random
import time


class Cocina:

    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = threading.Condition()
        self.vaso_ocupado = True

    def __beber_del_vaso(self):
        """
        Ponemos el vaso como ocupado y simulamos que
        se está bebiendo de él.
        Cuando se termina, notificamos al siguiente hilo
        en la cola.
        """
        self.vaso_ocupado = True
        self.print('comenzó a beber')
        time.sleep(int(random.randint(1, 3)))  # originalmente sería 10 acá
        self.print('terminó de beber')
        self.vaso_ocupado = False
        self.condition.notify()
        self.condition.release()

    @staticmethod
    def print(msg):
        print(f'{threading.current_thread().name} - {msg}')

    def esperando_el_vaso(self):
        """
        Se unen las instancias a un estado de espera,
        donde, cuando sean notificadas, recién podrán
        beber del vaso.
        """
        self.condition.acquire()
        while self.vaso_ocupado:
            self.print('esperando el vaso')
            self.condition.wait()
        self.__beber_del_vaso()

    def habilitar_vaso(self):
        """
        Notificamos a los hilos que se encuentran en espera,
        de que el vaso ya está disponible.
        """
        self.print('vaso habilitado')
        self.condition.acquire()
        self.vaso_ocupado = False
        self.condition.notify()
        self.condition.release()


cocina = Cocina()
for _ in range(5):  # originalmente sería 20 acá
    threading.Thread(target=cocina.esperando_el_vaso).start()
time.sleep(5)  # esperamos un ratito hasta habilitar el vaso
cocina.habilitar_vaso()
```

Output

```
Thread-11 - esperando el vaso
Thread-12 - esperando el vaso
Thread-13 - esperando el vaso
Thread-14 - esperando el vaso
Thread-15 - esperando el vaso
MainThread - vaso habilitado
Thread-11 - comenzó a beber
Thread-11 - terminó de beber
Thread-12 - comenzó a beber
Thread-12 - terminó de beber
Thread-13 - comenzó a beber
Thread-13 - terminó de beber
Thread-14 - comenzó a beber
Thread-14 - terminó de beber
Thread-15 - comenzó a beber
Thread-15 - terminó de beber
```